# How do I update the target DataFrame with values from source DataFrame that meet the condition?

Tags: pandas

This is my source DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'uid': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6],
    'grades': [69.233627, 70.130900, 83.357011, 88.206387, 74.342212]})
```

This is my target DataFrame

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'uid': [1, 2, 9],
                    'grades': [0.0,0.0,0.0]})
```

I'm trying to update the target DataFrame with values from source DataFrame that meet the condition.

```
for i in df2['uid']:
    if (len(df[df['uid']==i])>0):
        df2.loc[df2['uid']==i, 'grades']=df.loc[df['uid']==i, 'grades']
```

I've got what I need

```
>>> df2
uid grades
0   1   69.233627
1   2   70.130900
2   9   0.000000
```

I'd just like to know is there a simpler way to do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with set both index by `uid` columns:

```
df = df.set_index('uid')
df2 = df2.set_index('uid')

df2.update(df)
df2 = df2.reset_index()
print (df2)
   uid     grades
0    1  69.233627
1    2  70.130900
2    9   0.000000
```